# Duplicate row check in a datatable using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have data table like below. Here row 2,3,4,5 are not allowed. how do i validate this scenario using C#. Please help. Here the number of columns is not fixed.

---

```
  A             B             C
  A             B             C
  A             B             
  A                           C
                B             C
  A             B             B
  B             B             C
  A             C             B
```

Comment: Can you explain more, why row 2?

Comment: I tried looping through each row and concatinated values with some special characters and then compared the rows. But i want this in dynamic way like using Select or for each... do not want to use special characters to concatenate. To answer why row 2? Row 2,3,4,5 should be treated as duplicates for row1 (some business logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C# with LinQ**

This function eliminates duplicates and null values from columns. If is not null what you are looking for, then you just need to change "DBNull" for what you want.

```
public static DataTable FilterDataTable(DataTable table) 
    {
        // Erase duplicates
        DataView dv = new DataView(table);
        table = dv.ToTable(true, table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray()); 

        // Get Null values
        List<DataRow> toErase = new List<DataRow>();
        foreach (DataRow item in table.Rows)            
            for (int i = 0; i < item.ItemArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (item.ItemArray[i].GetType().Name == "DBNull")
                { toErase.Add(item); break; }

            }            
        //Erase Null Values
        foreach (DataRow item in toErase)            
            table.Rows.Remove(item);

        return table;            
    }
```